# Who captured Kokuo and killed Han?

Tags: naruto

In *Naruto*, as far as I know,

- 1-tail was captured by Deidara
- 2-tails was captured by Hidan
- 3-tails was captured by either Tobi or Deidara
- 4-tails was captured by Kisame
- 6-tails was captured by the Six Paths of Pain.
- 7-tails was captured by Kakuzu

So by process of elimination, Tobi, Konan, or Orochimaru were responsible for the capture of Kokuo. I ruled out Zetsu because in the data books he was faster than 4th Raikage and as strong as him. Alongside his mist armour makes it quite hard to picture Zetsu killing him.

Who captured 5-tails?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the simple and short answer is that we do not know who captured the [Han](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Han) and the 5-tails. It could have been anyone of the Akatsuki, including previous unnamed members.

Aside from knowing that the 5-tails *has* been captured, the only glimpse of information we have on when Han was possibly captured is mentioned by Deidara *Naruto Chapter 266*. We cannot say for certain which two Jinchuurki Deidara is mentioning here, as we're only shown a handful of tailed beasts being canonically captured. **Assuming** Han and the 5-tails was one of these two, then his capture was prior to the start of *Shippuden*

> [image: Naruto Chapter 266]